# How to send push notification on mobile devices(Android Crome) PWA

Tags: javascript, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I am new in PWA. I am using this code [Push notification](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/). I noticed this code is working on desktop. I want to try to see notification on my real Android  (Chrome) device.

When I send the notification, I am able to see it only on my desktop. Is it right? or am I doing something wrong? How can I send a notification on mobile devices  (Chrome) through PWA.

Comment: Can you please explain and are there any helpful website? I can follow

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stack overflow.
You can use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) to send push notification to your Android or iOS device.
For this task you can either use the provided Firebase SDK or use the console provided by the firebase to send push notifications directly to any device.